# How to get the peak of an audio file in python?

Tags: python, audio, pydub

How could I get the dB value of the peak of a wav file (for example, the peak of some wav file could be -6db, aka its loudest point is -6db) using python?

Comment: You would need some kind of signal processing library that you can use to identify the peak amplitude

Comment: As mention by @TylerLiu you could use wave and struct to get the peak of an audio file. Open the wav file with wave, and unpack the audio data using struct.unpack. Find the peak with max, and convert the peak value to dB

Comment: @Dexty How would that look like in code? Sorry I'm kind of new to this stuff

Comment: @prodohsamuel added an answer for you with a sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is an example of using wave, struct and math in Python to get the peak of an audio file.

```
import wave
import struct
import math

# Open the audio file
with wave.open('audio.wav', 'r') as audio:
    # Extract the raw audio data
    raw_data = audio.readframes(audio.getnframes())

# Convert the raw audio data to a list of integers
samples = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=audio.getnframes()), raw_data)

# Find the peak sample
peak = max(samples)

# Calculate the reference value based on the bit depth of the audio file
reference_value = 2**(audio.getsampwidth() * 8 - 1)

# Calculate the peak value in dBFS, using the maximum possible sample value as the reference value
peak_dB = 20 * math.log10(peak / reference_value)

print(peak_dB)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer on Christmas day <3